# Why is the table of contents positioned to the right by default?

Tags: table-of-contents

My question concerns the positioning of the table of contents in the `turabian-thesis` document class.

Typing this MWE...

```
\documentclass{turabian-thesis}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-7]

\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[8-12]

\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[13-20]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[21-44]

\end{document}
```

...produces this table of contents page (though I manually added a black border  into the screenshot for purposes of perspective):

[image]

**Question:** In the `turabian-thesis` document class, there is a large margin to the left of the table of contents. Why is this happening? And how can I reduce the size of the already-large left margin? Specifically, I want my TOC to have a 1-inch margin from the left and top, so that it can look like all the other TOCs out there.

Comment: The top level entries in this style are chapters not sections, what you are seeing is the indentation of sections under (missing) chapter headings.  Incidentally, you do not need the `\newpage` commands and the you are missing `\mainmatter` before the main body of the document, after the `\tableofcontents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed a bit your source and I hope you understand what you have asked. I hope that it works well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{turabian-thesis}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  inner=37.125mm,
  outer=33.4125mm,
  top=37.125mm,
  bottom=37.125mm,
  heightrounded,
  marginparwidth=51pt,
  marginparsep=17pt,
  headsep=24pt,
}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Large\bfseries}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-7]

\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[8-12]

\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[13-20]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[21-44]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you change the `tocdepth` counter, you should probably adjust the `secnumdepth` counter as well.

Comment: @Mico, Dear you are automatically authorized to modify my source if you found some parts to fix. Thank you so much for your assistance.